# How to import and use google fonts in .tsx file only in react?

Tags: reactjs, fonts, gatsby, styled-components, tsx

I want to import and use google fonts in `.tsx` file only.

Please read carefully I am not using any `css` file, so don’t suggest me to import it in css file and then use it. I have already searched a lot and everywhere I got solution of importing into css file.

I am using only `styled components`

Here is one of my file, please have look before any comments. https://gist.github.com/rohittagadiya/272e936a7e43b5f684a1c5ccca566c98

If you have look gist file then I want to use google font `Inter` which I have write in styled stuff.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.
Just need to install plugin [gatsby-plugin-google-fonts](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts/)